# Pandas adding some extra columns based on many conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am reading data in chunks from a CSV like this :

```
     for chunk in pd.read_csv(file, chunksize=50000, names = col_names, header = 0, dtype = dtype):
           chunk['derived_field_1'] = [1 if x == 'High' else -1 for x in chunk['indicator']]
```

The above is working and it is based on one condition. I want to do this based on conditions on two fields. Making the total number of combinations of values to be 8. As an example

```
    chunk['derived_field_2'] = [chunk['column_1'] if ((x == 'Red' for x in chunk['Color']) and (y == 'High' for y in chunk['Indicator'])) else
                          chunk['column_2'] if ((x == 'Green' for x in chunk['Color']) and (y == 'Low' for y in chunk['Indicator'])) else 0]
```

I want to do the above and keep going with the else condition for 6 more conditions like the above. This is failing, the two for loops are not working. I get this error -

```
raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Would anyone know the reason for this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy.where` for a vectorized solution:

```
import numpy as np
chunk['derived_field_2'] = (np.where((chunk['Color'] == "Red") & (chunk["Indicator"] == "High"), chunk["column_1"], 
   np.where((chunk['Color'] == "Green") & (chunk["Indicator"] == "Low"), chunk["column_2"], 0))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Hi this still raises the error : raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index. Have you faced this before? I set the min_itemsize to a higher number but that didnt work either

Comment: I can't think of a reason why it would fail. Just tested on a small file, seems to work fine.

Comment: Thanks it may be due to NaNs in these columns i think?

Comment: I would not think so. Normally, `NaNs` shouldn't give an error like this, This looks like the `len(chunk)` is not equal to the length of what is returned by `numpy.where`.

Comment: any idea as to why I would get the same error message when doing the following: conditions = [(df_combined['Weighted_Average_Search_Exits_After']<df_combined['Weighted_Average_Search_Exits_Before'])]
conditions2 = [(df_combined['Weighted_Average_Results_Pageviews/Search_After']<df_combined['Weighted_Average_Results_Pageviews/Search_Before'])]

df_combined['Comparison'] = np.where(conditions or conditions2, 'successful', 'unsuccessful')

df_combined